# PHP: Get value from the same array it's currently in

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to put a variable of an array in another element in the same array.

```
$list = array (
    array (
      "id"  =>  "9789045630816",
      "image"   =>  "<img src=\"images/" . array["id"] . ".png\">",
      "title"   =>  "Studio Webdesign"
    )
);
```

I'm trying to get `"image"` to hold `<img src="images/9789045630816.png">` .

Comment: What do you exactly want? Its not clear.

Comment: Try this: <?php echo $list[0][image]; ?>

Comment: is your array dynamic , i mean it may contain alot of elements (images) inside ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear why you can't just assign values to both array elements from a variable:

```
$id = '9789045630816';
$list = array(
  'id'    =>  $id,
  'image' =>  "<img src=\"images/$id.png\">",
  'title' =>  'Studio Webdesign'
);
```

Comment: This. Whatever creates the original array's `id` element, should additionally create the `image` element.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
$list = array(
        array
        (
        "id"    =>  "9789045630816",
        "image" =>  "<img src=\"images/",
        "title" =>  "Studio Webdesign"
                    )
        );
$list[0]['image'].=$list[0]["id"] . ".png\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

With static array declarations, you can't reference an element before the whole array is created.

I'm just brainstorming here, but to clean this up you could create a builder function instead:

```
function createItem($id, $title)
{
    return [
        'id' => $id,
        'image' => sprintf('<img src="images/%s.png" />', $id),
        'title' => $title,
    ];
}
```

And then:

```
$list = [createItem('9789045630816', 'Studio Webdesign')];
```

Comment: Of course, if one is going to create a function like that in order to create multiple such elements, then why not simply build the `<img>` tag using the value of the `id` element when needed?  That is, why store the `image` element in the array at all?

Comment: It's a fool that looks for logic in the chambers of the human heart ;-)